# Visualforce Phone and Email masking

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to display phone no in XXX-XXX-9999 format like if my phone no. is 1234567892 then it should display in XXX-XXX-7892.
Similarly my email should also be displayed in a****@****d.com eg. If my email id is abcde@gmail.com then it should display in a****@****l.com.

I know we can do this using some javascript but I want to know if we can achieve this using some standard functionality like the date format given below

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: I think platform encryption will help you here. Check on trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/spe_admins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript masking only hides in the rendered HTML output. Anyone can use developer tools to see the actual value. The best approach is to use Encryption as suggested by @highfive. But you can use combination of `RIGHT` and `LEFT` functions to get similar result in VF page. Hope this helps.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
    <apex:outputText value="XXX-XXX-{!RIGHT(Contact.MobilePhone,4)}"></apex:outputText><br></br>
    <apex:outputText value="{!LEFT(Contact.Email,1)}****@***{!RIGHT(Contact.Email,5)}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Screen

[image]